# How to prevent displaying "program terminated Unexpectedly" window?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have a C# WPF program using AciveX objects and providing WCF service. So there are many threads, many calls to unmanaged code. Sometimes under full load application crashes. I am investigating the problem - and it looks like problem is somewhere in ActiveX, which I can not change.  Anyhow I need a way to restore program after crash. As for now I have found solution:

```
public partial class App : Application
 {
    private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    bool isClosing = false;


    [System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionsAttribute]
    void D_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        log.FatalException("Error UnhandledException ", (Exception)e.ExceptionObject);
        MonitoringSvc.host.Close();
        log.Info("Restarting");
        if (!isClosing)
        {

            System.Windows.Forms.Application.Restart();
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }
    }


    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain D = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
        D.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(D_UnhandledException);
    }

    private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        isClosing = true;
    }
}
```

Program restarts on unhandled exception (on simulated for sure). But old copy stays unclosed with system message "program terminated Unexpectedly". Program does not interact with user most time so nobody can close that message to close the program. The question is how to silently close that old windows?

Comment: The attribute isn't enough, you also need [SecurityCritical].  Or use the `<legacyCorruptedStateExceptionPolicy>` element in the app.exe.config file.  Still no guarantee, the CLR can't catch hard exceptions in threads started by native code.  You'd need to disable WER for the process.  Ask at superuser.com.  These kind of bandaids are a bad rabbit-hole.

Comment: Maybe it is better to write simple guardian program. It can kill main process when it stops responding on some watchdog messages. And also restart when in exits unexpectedly. I am unsure about WER - will it be applied to child process?

Comment: I have found solution with SetErrorMode function plus one more trick. I will post it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is solution how to disable windows appearing on program crash. Not only WER, because even with WER disabled other window is shown (asking to close or debug program).

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int SetErrorMode(int wMode);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern FilterDelegate SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(FilterDelegate lpTopLevelExceptionFilter);
    public delegate bool FilterDelegate(Exception ex);

    App()
    {
        FilterDelegate fd = delegate(Exception ex)
        {
            return true;
        };
        SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(fd);

        SetErrorMode(SetErrorMode(0) | 0x0002 );
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I've just discovered an interesting thing: in fact, the delegate passed to the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter is not called. I think this is because SetUnhandledExceptionFilter expects a pointer to a native function, not a .NET delegate. We can just pass there (IntPtr)0 and the effect will be the same: exceptions will be silently ignored. But if we want to really handle exceptions with out managed function, we should place it into Dll, then retrieve its address, then give it to the SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. I haven't tried this though.